# $scope.$on use passed value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I get this problem when I send data with broadcast, here is my code:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('myEvent',{
   data:"value"
 });
```

and my on code:

```
$scope.$on('myEvent', (event, args) => {
     $scope.data = args.data;
     console.log($scope.data);
  });
  console.log($scope.data);
```

The problem is, that console.log inside function displays value, but outside I get undefined, what I missed?
thanks.

Comment: The code outside will run before the code inside does, so it's undefined at first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of your code is an asynchronous callback:

```
(event, args) => {
  $scope.data = args.data;
  console.log($scope.data);
}
```

That means it will run once the `myEvent` is triggered. The second console.log() will run immediately when that script and that particular line gets loaded by the browser and this part of your code is not async but synchronous. Because your code will in this case fully load before your event gets triggered, your "second" console.log() will run before the "first" one.

I suggest you read a bit about [how callbacks work](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/). It is one of the core patterns when working with javascript and it will help you a lot to understand how callbacks work in any of your future work.